# Getting no return value from die()

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how can I verify if I successfully deleted a row and store a flash a message on the session, so I thought rowCount() would be a good function for that, but it doesn't return anything at all. When I use die(), I just get a blank screen. Here's my function.

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare('
        DELETE FROM users WHERE id = :id
    ');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    die($count = $stmt->rowCount()); // I get no return value or anythhing on this line
                            // It just gives me a blank screen whether I enter a 
                            // valid id or not

    $msg = new \Plasticbrain\FlashMessages\FlashMessages();

    if (!session_id()) @session_start();
    if($count){
        $msg->success('User successfully deleted', 'index.php');   
    } else {
        $msg->error('User ID not existing', 'index.php');   
    }

    header("location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: To follow up with @YourCommonSense's answer, simply echo out the count, and then `die()`, or simply `exit;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and **not printed.**
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

So I developed a habit of doing always like this

```
var_dump($count);die;
```

as `var_dump()` can still give you some hint if value is not printable.